# jquery find closest attribute of preciding parent or there siblings

Tags: jquery

I need to find the attribute which is directly preceding each 'some data'. Any Idea?

```
<table>
  <tr attribute="1"><td>some data1</td></tr>
  <tr>              <td>some data2</td></tr>
  <tr>              <td>some data3</td></tr>
  <tr>              <td>some data4</td></tr>

  <tr attribute="2"><td>some data5</td></tr>
  <tr>              <td>some data6</td></tr>
  <tr>              <td>some data7</td></tr>

  <tr attribute="3"><td>some data8</td></tr>
  <tr>              <td>some data9</td></tr>
  <tr>              <td>some data10</td></tr>
  <tr>              <td>some data11</td></tr>
  <tr>              <td>some data12</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean by *I  need to find the attribute which is directly preceding each 'some data'*

Comment: You click on 'some data', and then I need to go in the DOM backwards until I find an attribute, the first one I find, so directly preceding.

Comment: can you add some proper content and explain with a sample

Comment: Yeah sure, I added an index to some data. So if I click on 'some data 1,2,3 or 4' I want to get .attr()=1. If I click on 'some data 5,6,or 7' I want to get .attr()=2 and so on

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NVx24/1/

Comment: I tried that code and it works too, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will traverse the DOM until it finds a `parent` that has an `attribute`.

http://jsfiddle.net/u24cH/3/

```
function getAttribute($parent){
    if($parent.index() !== 0) {
        if($parent.attr('attribute')) {
            return $parent.attr('attribute')
        } else {
            return getAttribute($parent.prev());
        }
    } else {
        return $parent.attr('attribute')
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, it works exactly as it should. I call it this way, is that right: getAttribute($(this).parent("tr"));

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute selector followed by a contains.

```
$('tr[attribute] td:contains("some data")').each(function() {
   var attrValue = $(this).parent().attr('attribute');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Ctzk/